# How to add constraints to elements of a list in other predicates?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to do a Sudoku solver in SICStus Prolog using the *clpfd* library, but it should be similar to other implementations like SWI-Prolog.
The main predicate is something like:

```
solve(Board) :-
    length(Board, 81),
    domain(Board, 1, 9),
    restrict_board(Board),
    labeling([], Board).
```

The return of solve is all possible combinations, the first answer is [1, 1, 1, ..., 1],
if I ask for another is [1, 1, 1, ..., 2] and so on.

So my problem is in the restriction, now my code looks like this (the predicate get_cells is working and returns a list with the positions of the cells of that row, column or square):

```
restrict(Name, Board) :-
    restrict(Name, Board, 9).
restrict(_, _, 0) :- !.
restrict(Name, Board, Actual) :-
    get_cells(Name, Actual, Cells),
    get_board_cells(Board, Cells, Elements),
    all_different(Elements),
    New is Actual - 1,
    restrict(Name, Board, New).

restrict_board(Board) :-
    restrict(row, Board),
    restrict(col, Board),
    restrict(square, Board).
```

I think the problem lies in the get_board_cells predicate

```
get_board_cells(Board, List, Cells) :-
    findall(Cell, (
        member(Pos, List),
        nth0(Pos, Board, Cell)
    ), Cells).
```

because the cells are copies of the original that does not have a single element instanciated, but prolog seems to not restrict the original board, only the copies of the elements, how could I get the original Board elements to be restricted?

Comment: _"because the cells are copies of the original"_ - as far as I know, this intuition correct. findall definitely creates copies of anything it "finds", duplicating unbound variables too. You will have to eschew findall and write a less generic "all solutions finder" that collects the oiginal unbound variables.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidTonhofer, it was the findall, I did not thought it was just that, just for future references I changed the get_board_cells predicate to:

`get_board_cells(_, [], []) :- !.  
get_board_cells(Board, [Head | Body], [Cell | Cells]) :- nth0(Head, Board, Cell), get_board_cells(Board, Body, Cells).`

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. I know that `findall/3` creates new copies of the unbound variables, but: `(0 #=< X, X #< Y, Y #< Z, Z #=< 3), findall(K, member(K,[X,Y,Z]) , L), label(L).` actually works properly! (*confused*)

Comment: Maybe this is a SICStus difference, but this does not work here `(0 #=< X, X #< Y, Y #< Z, Z #=< 3), findall(K, member(K,[X,Y,Z]) , L), labeling([], L).`, only works with `L = [X,Y,Z]` instead of the `findall/3`

Comment: Thank you. I'm using SWI-Prolog, so yes, probably a difference in behaviour here.